# Shortcut keys are working during editing a node in treeview

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, treeview

I have a treeview in my form. It has a context menu strip associated with it.
Context menu strip has items like:- **create a new node, create sub node, rename node, delete node**.
I have shortcuts for all these items.

My problem is, when i am creating a new node(entering text for the node), if i press **Ctrl+S**(shortcut key for creating sub node), it is firing the click event of the "Create sub node" item.

This happens for all the items in the context menu strip.

Now,
 1. How can i stop the shortcut keys to fire when i am still editing or creating a node?
 2. Is there any property or event which should be handled to stop the shortcut keys to fire the respective events during the editing or creating a node?

Need resolution for this ASAP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you enter the name for the new node, you can subscribe to the `PreviewKeyDown` event of the tree view or the tree view item.

To prevent a certain key press from firing a shortcut, you can set the handled property to true. The following example assumes, that you enter the name for the new node into a textbox.

```
private void UIElement_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is TextBox && (e.Key == Key.LeftCtrl || e.Key == Key.RightCtrl))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

The idea is, to prevent any shortcuts from happening, as long as they come from the textbox. Since only the control key is handled, this shouldn't swallow any other keys you might want to enter for the name.